# Set price range on WooCommerce products without setting up variables

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, custom-fields, price

IN woocommerce I would like to be able to put a price range on my simple products without setting a variable product as I don't need that.

See the link below: https://www.tnbloom.com.au/product/memorial-wreath/

For example, instead of the actual price of **$45**, I would like to replace it by **$45 - $120** *(without setting variable product)*.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: it's very doable, but why? I asked because even if you can do that, what would happen if this product is added to cart? what price will it use then?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The following code will add a custom price field in the product options pricing settings, to set the max price for your displayed price range. So you will have to set that max price for each product.

Then it will display on front end a price range, on shop, archives and single product pages, only if the max range field has a price set for it.

The code:

```
// Add a custom field for price range to product in backend
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_options_pricing', 'add_field_product_options_pricing' );
function add_field_product_options_pricing() {
    global $post;

    echo '<div class="options_group show_if_simple">';

    woocommerce_wp_text_input( array(
        'id'            => '_max_price_for_range',
        'label'         => __('Max price for range', 'woocommerce').' ('.get_woocommerce_currency_symbol().')',
        'placeholder'   => __('Set the max price for range', 'woocommerce'),
        'description'   => __('Set the max price for range, to activate it…', 'woocommerce'),
        'desc_tip'      => 'true',
    ));

    echo '</div>';
}

// Save product custom field to database when submitted in Backend
add_action( 'woocommerce_process_product_meta', 'save_product_options_custom_fields', 30, 1 );
function save_product_options_custom_fields( $post_id ){
    // Saving custom field value
    if( isset( $_POST['_max_price_for_range'] ) ){
        update_post_meta( $post_id, '_max_price_for_range', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['_max_price_for_range'] ) );
    }
}

// Frontend: display a price range when the max price is set for the product
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'custom_range_price_format', 10, 2 );
function custom_range_price_format( $price, $product ) {

    // Only for simple product type
    if( $product->is_type('simple') ){
        // Get the max price for range
        $max_price = get_post_meta( $product->get_id(), '_max_price_for_range', true );

        if( empty($max_price) )
            return $price; // exit

        $active_price = wc_get_price_to_display( $product, array( 'price' => $product->get_price() ) );

        $price = sprintf( '%s &ndash; %s', wc_price($active_price), wc_price($max_price) );
    }
    return $price;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

In backend product option settings:

[image]

Frontend products:

[image]

Comment: Hi, This is what I was exactly looking for. Thanks. I would like to update Price Filter Widget accordingly. Any idea how it can be done? I am analysing class-wc-widget-price-filter.php file but unable to understand. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I was able to achieve this by updating the code  'max_price'  => get_post_meta( $id, '_max_price_for_range', true ), in woocommerce/includes/data-stores/class-wc-product-data-store-cpt.php

Comment: Simple and concise!